# Can't find the motherboard model number on my hp envy h8-1414?

Tags: drivers, motherboard, hp-envy

I have a motherboard inside my HP Envy H8-1414, and written on it is `Angelica Rev 1.2` and also the number `M3970CM` but absolutely no mention of the model number.  I've gone to the Gigabyte Website looking for drivers for Windows 7, and found 3 model numbers which claim to be my mother board....

On HP's site I found out that the machine has a AM3-b type socket, and when I went to the [Gigabyte's website](http://www.gigabyte.us/support-downloads/download-center.aspx?kw=M3970AM) and selected Motherboard, then `Socket AM3+`, then selected a chipset of `AMD 970` but I'm confounded by the `model name` since I can't find it on my motherboard.

Comment: There might not be a specifications document on the motherboard.  The motherboard could be an entirely custom motherboard specifically made for HP for this laptop.

Comment: Does the HP site not have the drivers?  Theya re usually quite good at providing for their systems.

Comment: They do have the drivers, for Windows 8, but I'm back sliding to Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), it detects the make and model of motherboards.
[SiSoft Sandra](http://www.sisoftware.co.uk/?d=news&f=2013_release&l=en&a=) also will detect motherboard make and model.
I have used both in the past and they work well.

Also, be aware some computer manufacturers, use custom motherboards from other manufacturers.  Just because it has Gigabyte on the motherboard, does not mean that Gigabyte will support it, or will provide drivers for it.  It could be that HP is solely responsible for support.

Comment: +1 for needing drivers from the OEM (HP in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You can find motherboard specification at [Motherboard Specifications, M3970AM-HP](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03353629&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&product=5296859).

Also as Keltari said, you can use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).